# Basic solution for adding list item to combo box via code on load

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

## What I need:

1. I was a basic equivalent of a select box i.e. a combobox of dropdown list style (that preferably doesn't allow text input).
2. I need to add the list items by code rather than the property box.

## What I have:

```
Private Sub Form_Load ()
   ComboStaffMember.AddItem "John Murphy"
End Sub
```

...produces "...add item is not a member of system.windows.forms.comboxbox".

```
Private Sub Form_Load ()
   ComboStaffMember.Items.Add("John Murphy")
End Sub
```

...produces no result.

## My question:

Why is the item not adding? The form name is FrmStaffLogIn and it's in Form1.vb. Should Form_Load correspond to either of these or is my code incorrect elsewhere?

Comment: open the list, you'll see it.  `Additem` fails because you cant make up your own methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working code:**

```
Private Sub FrmIdentCust_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboStaffMember.Items.Add("John Murphy")
End Sub
```

I was missing `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put combo add statement in following format in form load event :

```
   Private Sub Form_Load () 

   Me.ComboStaffMember.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry("Text to be displayed", 1))

   End Sub
```

Comment: I was missing `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load` after Form_Load. Full working code here for context: http://pastebin.com/w06iEcP7

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your code line `ComboStaffMember.Items.Add("John Murphy")` doesn't work? it should work just fine.

The `Add()` method On `Item` collection expects `object` parameter and `string` as well can be passed as argument to it. Like below [C# code sample]:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(
                   new string[] {"SomeText","SomeOtherText","LastText"});
```

Also, you probably don't see any item cause you haven't set a default selected item. Just expand the dropdown and you will see the items. To set the default selected item

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I was missing `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load` after Form_Load. Full working code here for context: http://pastebin.com/w06iEcP7